# readline in a C program obeys history-search-backward and history-search-forward

Tags: command-history, readline

I would like to use readline in a C program, with history-search-backward and history-search-forward triggered by the up and down arrows.  I tried things like

```
rl_parse_and_bind("\"\e[A\":history-search-backward");
rl_parse_and_bind("\"\e[B\":history-search-forward");
```

in my program, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was using libedit-dev.  libreadline6-dev worked.